# eMMC chip, Vcc voltage is leaking to Vccq

Tags: circuit-analysis, storage, emmc

I'm trying to develop a device similar to exploiteer.rs' [low voltage eMMC adapter](https://www.exploitee.rs/index.php/Exploitee.rs_Low_Voltage_e-MMC_Adapter), but with the form of a microSD card adapter.

Today when I was testing, I found that the eMMC chips are **outputting** voltages from Vccq pin (around 2.1 - 2.5v depending on the model of eMMC chip) either when connected to the LDO regulator's 1.8v output or kept floating.

I tried with eMMC chips that has "3.3v Vcc, 3.3/1.8v Vccq"(dual voltage) and "3.3v Vcc, 1.8v Vccq"(low voltage), both have the same behavior.

I checked multiple times that the only thing that has 3.3v on my adapter is the Vcc rail, so any voltage higher than 1.8v can only come from Vcc.

I'm not familiar with the internals of an eMMC chip so I'm not sure if this is normal or not. But on the low voltage eMMC this behavior is clearly affecting its normal operation because Vccq rail has way higher voltage than it can accept.

Can someone explain the possible reason for Vcc voltage to leak into Vccq rail? I'm sure there are no shorts between Vcc and Vccq when soldering.

The eMMC solder pad in my design is modified from [voltlog's eMMC to microSD adapter](https://github.com/voltlog/emmc-wfbga153-microsd). Only thing I modified is trace out the Vccq rail to a header pin to allow separate voltage input.
I hope seeing the exact layout instead of a schematic can give more clue about what's going on so here it is:
[image]

Comment: Probably not related to your issue, but why have you left C6 (Vccq) unconnected?

Comment: @brhans It's quite cumbersome to route a trace just for C6, and I've checked with a multimeter that all Vccq pads are internally connected, so I decided to left C6 alone.

Comment: Can you share the part number of the specific eMMC you're using?

Comment: @brhans The model of eMMCs I've tested are KIOXIA (TOSHIBA) THGBMFG7C1LBAIL and THGAMRG7T13BAIL, also a Samsung eMMC I failed to recall exact model name right now. I'm not sure if it's ok to share the link to the datasheets but they should be relatively easy to find on Google.

Comment: @brhans  I (kinda) found the problem. K5(marked as Vcc) is actually RST_n pin and it is an I/O pin, which should only get maximum 1.95v on low voltage eMMCs. After manually cutting the trace, the voltage that appears on Vccq pin for low voltage eMMC significantly decreased and could be "suppressed" by LDO regulator's 1.8v output and have the chip working correctly.